# PHP Regex string extract with text & comma

Tags: php, regex

I'm having some problems with a Regex string, it's simple but not getting it...

The string is;

Hi Name, (new line)

So I want to extract the Name from 'Hi Name,'

Any ideas, I know it's really simple? Or is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$re = '/Hi (.*)?,/';
$str = 'Hi Terry,';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Your $str is your string and $matches is populated with the result. You can access it like...

```
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply... I had this
/Hi (.*)$/m
Which got some results, but out of 140 it got one, and so did the one you posted which makes me think there might be another issue I have overlooked

Comment: No problem. Please upvote or mark my response as answered if it helped!

Comment: The text lies between some HTML 

<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px" class="welcome">Hi Terry,</span>

So out of 140, I would say 90% of them use this so not sure why so little results

Comment: Maybe try preg_match_all($re,$str,$matches);